# Field "Placement" in Facebook Marketing Adindsight API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I have error with field Placement
Placement field it's not a country, but diversification between facebook audience, facebook and instagram... My full request is:

```
    account = AdAccount('act_46605285454545442')
    ads = account.get_ads()
params = {
    'time_range': {
        'since':  "2019-06-01", 
        'until': "2019-06-26"
        }, 
    'fields': [
        AdsInsights.Field.campaign_id,
        AdsInsights.Field.campaign_name,
        AdsInsights.Field.adset_name,
        AdsInsights.Field.ad_name,
        AdsInsights.Field.spend,
        AdsInsights.Field.impressions,
        AdsInsights.Field.clicks,
        AdsInsights.Field.buying_type,
        AdsInsights.Field.objective,        
        AdsInsights.Field.actions,
        AdsInsights.Field.cpm,
        AdsInsights.Field.account_currency,
        AdsInsights.Field.placement,
     ],
    'level': 'ad',
    'time_increment': 'all_days',
}
async_job = account.get_insights_async(fields = params.get('fields'), params=params)
```

And it gives me error:  "placement is not valid for fields param"

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge "country" isn't a field, its a breakdown. Sounds like you have it in the wrong place in your request. Can't know for sure though, because you haven't posted any other details.